# Convertir un arreglo a un archivo .json

Tags: javascript, nodejs

bueno este es mi codigo

`var miJson = JSON.stringify(miArray)`;

pero yo necesito que todos los datos de la variable "miJson" esten en un archivo con la extension .json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Puedes crear archivos usando la **[API de File System](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html)**

Por ejemplo:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'miJson.json';
var data = JSON.stringify(miArray);

fs.writeFile(file, data, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("El archivo se guardo con exito!");
});
```